# Android Program to show data that is represented graphically

Tags: java, android, json

This is my question i  want you to use the API hosted at http://212.88.98.116:4050/. This is a simple json API showing some live data. i want to create android program that presents a graphical representation(Bar,line graph) of the data using android java language.Please i need your help just 5 hours from now.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: so How far you are to make this?

Comment: This is a new problem presented to me, i have never tried solving such, you can also recommend me to any link where i can get the best answer

Comment: SO is not a proper website for these kind of problems. Please try posting somewhere else.

Comment: I have tried to edit the question again (just i need that data to be represented in either bar graph or line graph).

Comment: Reaz Murshed Masud,Nigam Patro,Milind Vyas and others i need you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use a third party library for this.
MPAndroid is quite popural :
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335
Download the data from your code and use this simple API to create a bar graph.

Comment: Hey Nikos thanks, but what i want is to get a way to link this  ip address (http://212.88.98.116:4050/) containing JSONArray data , so that the data retrieved   draws a line graph with its own data automatically

Comment: You need a way to "read" the data from your android code first. In order to do this data should be exposed in a way so that android can "get" them. Can you access the servers code? If so implement a rest web service or something. But before you go to the graph you have to açcess the data somehow.

Comment: Mr.Nikos, Here is the full description.

Comment: In this small task we want you to use the API hosted at http://212.88.98.116:4050/. This is a simple json API showing some live data. Your task is to create a program that presents a graphical representation of the data in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: I think now we create any program, irrespective of the android

Comment: Then you can do this by downloading the html page , parse it using again a third party library, and then extract the data and feed them to another third party api ( there are numerous again, for java). But I cannot figure out another way to do this. You still need extra libraries to do this. Hope this helped you a litle

Comment: Is this a class assignment or work project; Maybe you should clarify in what framework exactly you have  to do this. Is it a simple java SE program?